# Bash getting lines between a line number and a pattern

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a function that should get lines between specific line number, that is passed to it and store in a variable, and the next line with the pattern 'endhelp'

The code I have now:

```
START_LINE=$1 #-- On which line the help is and where the search should start

#-- Where the help command block ends
END_LINE[1]=$(sed -n "$START_LINE,/endhelp/p=" filename)

#-- Add one number to END_LINE as a second array value to speed line extracting
END_LINE[2]=$((${END_LINE[1]}+1))

#-- The actual line extraction that outputs the whole lines
sed -n "$START_LINE,${END_LINE[1]}p; ${END_LINE[2]}q" filename
```

So if I would have something like this: (NOTE: there are other similar blocks in the input file, so that's why the starting line is important)

```
-- some text --

help 
    text and some more text
    more words and text
    third help thing line
    stuff
    hi
endhelp

-- some other text --
```

The output would be:

```
text and some more text
more words and text
third help thing line
stuff
hi
```

Would the above code work and could it be done more efficiently? Also how to make it stop when it detects an empty line with only the string 'endhelp'?

**UPDATE**

Here is the updated code that does what I want it to do:

```
START_LINE=$2 #-- Where the help command block starts
awk 'BEGIN {OUTPUT=0} NR=='$START_LINE' {OUTPUT=1} /^endhelp$/ {exit} OUTPUT'
```

It stops if the line *only* has the string 'endhelp' and starts printing from $START_LINE. I added the `BEGIN {OUTPUT=0}` because it otherwise gave an error on some older devices.

**UPDATE2**

I edited the code once more, to fix it exiting if it sees 'endhelp' on an otherwise empty line before it gets to 'START_LINE':

```
awk 'NR>='$START_LINE' {if ($0 ~ /^endhelp$/) {exit} else {$1=$1; print}}'
```

It's smaller and a tiny bit faster. It also has the added `$1=$1`, that removes trailing and leading whitespaces from the current line. It can be safely removed if not needed.

Comment: What line # are you passing to script?

Comment: The line where 'help' is, so it would start printing from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> could it be done more efficiently? Also how to make it stop when it detects an empty line with only the string 'endhelp'?

Here is one awk version that will be more efficient than your script:

```
awk -v n=$1 '/^endhelp$/{exit} p; NR==n || /^help$/{p=1}' file
```

This will start printing either from a given line number OR when a line has just `help` text in it. It will keep printing till a line with `endhelp` text appears. At that point `awk` will just `exit` and rest of the file will not be processed.

Comment: Thank you! I edit my code based on this and it works wonders!

Answer (score 1):

If you are already searching for the start line, why not just print between those anchors?

In Perl for example given:

```
$ echo "$help_text" 
help 1
    text 1 and some more text
    more words and text
    third help thing line
    stuff
    hi
endhelp

help 2
    text 2 and some more text
    more words and text
    third help thing line
    stuff
    hi
endhelp

help 3
    text 3 and some more text
    more words and text
    third help thing line
    stuff
    hi
endhelp
```

You can print the text between the anchor `help \d` and `endhelp` like so:

```
$ echo "$help_text" | perl -0777 -ne 'print $1 if /^help[ \t]+3(.*?)^endhelp/ms'

    text 3 and some more text
    more words and text
    third help thing line
    stuff
    hi
```

In awk:

```
$ echo "$help_text" | awk '
> /^help 3/ {flag=1; next}
> /^endhelp/ {flag=0}
> flag {print}'
    text 3 and some more text
    more words and text
    third help thing line
    stuff
    hi
```

If you are set on using the line number as the start of the block, you can do:

```
$ echo "$help_text" | awk '
NR==17 {flag=1; next}
/^endhelp/ {flag=0}
flag {print}'
    text 3 and some more text
    more words and text
    third help thing line
    stuff
    hi
```

Comment: Other wise it works, but it breaks if the line starts with 'endhelp' and I want it to stop if the line has only the string 'endhelp'. But thank you for leading me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use `awk` oneliner to extract lines you need:

```
awk "NR==$1 && /help/ {flag=1;next}/endhelp/{flag=0}flag" filename
```

> input filename and NR==3:

```
-- some text --

help 
    text and some more text
    more words and text
    third help thing line
    stuff
    hi
endhelp

-- some other text --
```

> output:

```
text and some more text
more words and text
third help thing line
stuff
hi
```

You can also do it this way, just specifying the line number:

```
awk "NR==$1 {flag=1;next}/endhelp/{flag=0}flag" filename
```

Comment: I thought about using awk and this is otherwise fine, but the line where shearching should start is given to the function. There can be multiple `help text more text endhelp` segments in the input file so simply having it start from the first `help` to the `endhelp` won't work. I'll add this to the question for future answers.

Comment: you can specify line number to start with

Comment: By having `awk '$'$START_LINE',{flag=1;next}/endhelp/{flag=0}flag' filename`?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this stops printing the lines if there is 'endhelp' anywhere in the line. It should only stop if the line is otherwise empty, but thank you for pointing me to the right direction.